# Difference between SQLContext.createDataframe(RDD, StructType) vs. SQLContext.read().schema(StructType).json(RDD) if I am reading in JSON strings?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

[createDataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#createDataFrame(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD,%20org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType))

and

[read.schema().json()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) seem to serve same function if we give in string of JSON?

EDIT:

I seem to have found a third option:

[JsonRDD.jsonStringtoRow](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/json/JsonRDD.html#jsonStringToRow(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType, java.lang.String))

Comment: The createDataFrame method doesn't accept an RDD of strings which are JSON

Comment: Also, you tagged this with scala, yet you've linked to the JavaDoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLContext.createDataframe(RDD, StructType)` here, the first parameter is RDD of string which is not in JSON format. It needs to be `Row`s of RDD.

`SQLContext.read().schema(StructType).json(RDD)` here, the parameter RDD should be a string with json format.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a JSON dataset, you can load it into a dataframe using `spark.read.json` in Scala. From the [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-dataframes):

```
val df = spark.read.json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json")

// Displays the content of the DataFrame to stdout
df.show()
// +----+-------+
// | age|   name|
// +----+-------+
// |null|Michael|
// |  30|   Andy|
// |  19| Justin|
// +----+-------+
```

`createDataFrame(rdd)` will work when your RDD contains `Row` objects. Spark will [infer the data types](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection), or you can [specify the schema](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema) (which I would recommend unless you're certain that your data doesn't contain anything peculiar).